# If a semiring $R$ has right cancellation property and $aR=R$ for some $a$ then show that $R$ has idempotent.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, semiring

> - Let $R$ be a semi-ring. Let the right cancellation property hold in $R$.
>     Show that if $Ra=R$  for some $a\in R$ then show that $R$ has an idempotent.

Since $a\in R\implies \exists c\in R$ such that $ca=a\implies c^2a=ca\implies c^2=c\implies c$
is idempotent.

*Question*:

> - Let $R$ be a semi-ring. Let the right cancellation property hold in $R$.
>     Show that if $aR=R$  for some $a\in R$ then show that $R$ has an idempotent.

Since $a\in R\implies \exists c\in R$ such that $ac=a$.

But I can't proceed further. Please give some hints to proceed.I am wondering if it is true.

Comment: I assume your definition of semiring does not include the existence of $0$?

Comment: Yes you are right ;$(R,+)$ is a commutative semigroup and $(R,.)$ is a semigroup

Comment: By not reading correctly, my fault :p

Comment: Where did you find this question, maybe they meant left cancellation property in the second statement? I'm not really into semi-ring theory and don't know too many interesting examples to potentially find a counterexample.

Comment: if it is  so then we have nothing to do@Mathematician42